# Efficient matrix indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `A` of size 256 X 16, and a second matrix `B` of size 8 X 8, where every element of `B` is an integer in the range `[0, 15]`. If A was just a row vector (i.e. of size 1X16) then `C = A[B]` would output an 8X8 matrix where `Cij = A[bij]`. Is there any efficient way I could do the same if `A` is 256X16 using numpy (or anything else)? I mean that I want an output matrix `C` of size 256 X 8 X 8 (i.e., `B` is indexing every row of `A`).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think that I solved it:

```
C = A[:, B]
```